# How to create App from Database Link on Apex

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I have APEX installed on-premise.
I have created a database link to a remote database, to a schema call SIC.
How can I create a page from the database link instead of the local SCHEMA (OBE)?

I can get data (from the SIC SCHEMA) from the SQL Workshop, running queries, but I can't seem to figure out how to load data to the application from the create application, and then create page?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell, you'll need a 2-step workaround:

- create synonym that looks at the remote table, e.g.

  ```
  create synonym syn_emp for emp@dbl_orcl;
  ```
- as Apex "Create page Wizard" knows only tables or views, you'll have to create a view:

  ```
  create or replace view v_syn_emp as select * from syn_emp;
  ```

Now run the wizard; select the `V_SYN_EMP` view as page source. Once you're done, navigate to region's properties and overtype source name (from `V_SYN_EMP` to `SYN_EMP`, i.e. a synonym instead of a view).

Now you can drop the view; you don't need it any more.

```
drop view v_syn_emp;
```

Comment: And then if a need to edit this information what is the next step, as the view is dropped. Does it update trought the synonym?

Comment: That's what synonym is used for.

Comment: Thank you. I am still learning all this :)